npm run build giving errors in React Hook Functions
i am using nextjs 14
python-course/page.tsx

when i am running npm run build on my project, this page is giving error
this is my package.json
``
{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
},
"browser": {
"child process": "false"
},
"dependencies": {
"@clerk/nextjs": "^4.29.9",
"@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.2.0",
"@tsparticles/engine": "^3.3.0",
"@tsparticles/react": "^3.0.0",
"@tsparticles/slim": "^3.3.0",
"axios": "^1.6.7",
"body-parser": "^1.20.2",
"child_process": "^1.0.2",
"child-process": "^1.0.2",
"clerk": "^0.8.3",
"clsx": "^2.1.0",
"dotenv": "^16.4.5",
"express": "^4.19.2",
"firebase": "^10.0.0",
"react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
"framer-motion": "^11.0.12",
"isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
"mini-svg-data-uri": "^1.4.4",
"mongodb": "^6.5.0",
"mongoose": "^8.3.0",
"next": "14.0.4",
"raw-body": "^2.5.2",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",
"react-icons": "^5.0.1",
"react-monaco-editor": "^0.55.0",
"react-resizable": "^3.0.5",
"react-split": "^2.0.14",
"sharp": "^0.33.2",
"stripe": "^14.23.0",
"swr": "1.1.2",
"tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
"unfetch": "^5.0.0"

},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^20",
"@types/raw-body": "^2.3.0",
"@types/react": "^18",
"@types/react-dom": "^18",
"autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
"eslint": "^8",
"eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
"postcss": "^8",
"tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
"typescript": "^5"
}
}
``
i have never faced this type of error before and cannot get any solution from the internet

To tell what is a component, the lint rule uses the naming convention that components start with uppercase. So change const page to const Page.

Put your 'page function name first character in capital letter like this 'Page'.
React components name must start with First letter capital.
Now your problem fixed
Tips: you should use handleScroll function outside of useEffect and pass it inside [].

you should use handleScroll function outside of useEffect and pass it inside []. Why's that? Looks to me like that will just cause it to unsubscribe/resubscribe on each render. It's not harmful, but it's also not necessary or desired.

It's not necessary. But in case if you want to use it outside useEffect you will get error of undefined. It's fine unless you call that function outside useEffect..
